# How to create a event in MS Teams Calendar using MS Graph API from a backend service

Tags: api, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am a beginner in using Microsoft Graph API, I really interested to implement the Graph API possibilities in my .Net Core application. I decided to create a sample application, that create meetings in MS Teams app. I have already done the steps listed below.

1. I register a new app in Azure Active Directory.
2. Assign 'Calendars.Read' and 'Calendars.ReadWrite' (Permission type - Application) permissions.

I know there are two types of authentication for permission, `Delegated` and `Application`.

**Permissions**

[image]

**Code**

```
try
        {
            var config = this.LoadAppSettings();

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(config);

            var @event = new Event
            {
                Subject = "My event by ragesh",
                Start = new DateTimeTimeZone
                {
                    DateTime = "2020-06-11T07:44:21.358Z",
                    TimeZone = "UTC"
                },
                End = new DateTimeTimeZone
                {
                    DateTime = "2020-06-18T07:44:21.358Z",
                    TimeZone = "UTC"
                }
            };

            await graphClient.Me.Events
             .Request()
             .AddAsync(@event);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

But when I execute my code to create `events` in graph API it shows an authentication error.

**Error**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you use application permissions, you cannot use the `/me` API url segment, since there is no authenticated user. You must instead use `/users/<user-id>` in it's place.

You're using the .NET SDK, so that translates to you cannot use `graphClient.Me`, you must use `graphClient.Users[userId]`.